# Javascript Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /ID:(.*)) on local/: Unmatched ')'

Tags: javascript, regex

With the function below I am trying to get it to retrieve the number 1003567400 by looking between 2 string variables set as start and end.

Here is the data:

```
data = ('(ID: 1003567400) on local');
```

And here is the code:

```
var start = "ID:";
var end = ") on Local";
var testRE = data.match(start + "(.*)" + end);
console.log(testRE[1]);
```

The error is:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /ID:(.*)) on local/: Unmatched ')' at String.match (native)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: The error message and your code don't match. Check the regex from the error message and compare it with `end`

Comment: I copied your code and it works flawlessly for me (although I should add, the regex does not match the string). But if you look at the expression in your error message `/ID:(.*)) on local/` you'll notice there are two closing parentheses `))`. Parentheses are reserved characters in regexes and should be escaped.

Comment: Sorry misstype...Changed to this part: var end = ") on Local";  ...should give the error now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
data = ('(ID: 1003567400) on local');

console.log(data.match(/\(ID: (.*)\) on local/));
```

Here's what you need: https://regex101.com/r/qtckPB/1

Your regex will be: `\(ID: (.*)\) on local`

`data.match(/\(ID: (.*)\) on local/);` will return you value

Answer (score 0):

var start = "(ID:"; instead of var start = "ID:";